# Which companions return for knights of the fallen empire/eternal throne?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So I just finished Star Wars: Knights of the Fallen Empire chapter one. And I heard that most companions will not be returning to the alliance. Which of the class companions will make a return for the story and join the alliance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source for these: I played all of both expansions (so far) and did every recruitment mission.  No companions return in KotET as yet, these are all from KotFE.

#### General

- C2-N2
- 2V-R8

Also, Treek and HK-51 are unaffected.

#### Knight

- T7-01
- Sergeant Rusk*

#### Consular

- Qyzen Fess

#### Trooper

- Aric Jorgan
- M1-4X
- Yuun

Also, Tanno Vik appears but does not return.

#### Smuggler

- Bowdaar
- Guss Tuno

#### Sith Warrior

- Vette
- Broonmark
- Lieutenant Pierce

#### Sith Inquisitor

- Talos Drellik
- Xalek

#### Imperial Agent

- Kaliyo Djannis
- Scorpio (briefly)
- Dr. Lokin

#### Bounty Hunter

- Skadge*
- Gault
- Torian
- Blizz

<sub>** mutually exclusive*</sub>

One companion also dies in KotET:

> Either Torian or Vette

Comment: Thanks this really helps. I wonder what happens to the others though.

Comment: You can get companions back from the bottom of the base on Odessen. I was able to get Nadia Grell back as a Jedi Consular. I've only played KotFE, not KotET.

Comment: @Clomp Yup, that's bypassing the story and just retrieving all of the base companions.  Worth mentioning though!